# Which non-stop passenger flight connects two cities with the largest temperature difference?

Tags: air-travel, weather-and-climate, factoids, routes

For the purpose of this question,

- temperature refers to daily mean temperature in a month (shown as "daily mean" on Wikipedia) of the city/town that an airport primarily serves
- passenger flight refers to scheduled flights and public charters with a published schedule
- it can be any month of the year

Example:

Singapore (SIN) - Moscow (DME) SQ 362 in February, daily mean for Singapore 27.1°C, daily mean for Moscow -6.7°C, difference **33.8°C**.

Comment: I took a flight from Miami to Cleveland on 19-Jan-1994. 70F (21C) when we left Miami. -20F (-29C) when we got to Cleveland. Total difference: 90F (50C). Not an answer as this was a one-off occurrence - the -20 in Cleveland set a new record.

Comment: So far, the answers go from northern hemisphere to southern in Jan/Feb.  What’s the coldest airport/month in the south, and the opposite in the north?  I left Spain one June just before it reached 38°C.

Comment: @WGroleau There's a lot less land mass in the southern hemisphere, and (AFAIK) no major cities where monthly average temps are negative.  Even Ushuaia, at the southern tip of South America, and Queenstown, ski capital of southern New Zealand, stay above zero in town in July.

Comment: @WGroleau All the cities given so far are north of the equator, if only just.

Comment: I was so sure Singapore was below that I didn’t even bother to check.

Comment: When you say “passenger flight”, do you mean _scheduled_ passenger flight? Or do flights carrying personnel to and from Antarctic research stations count?

Comment: @MikeScott I have edited the question to clarify it.

Comment: @NateEldredge What is the flight number? I can't find a non-stop flight from Acapulco to Winnipeg on Google Flights.

Comment: @Asura: Oops, I think I mixed up two flights.  Next best seems to be Ixtapa-Zihuatanejo to Winnipeg: Sunwing WG484 ZIH-YWG.  Zihuatanejo has a January average of 25.5 and Winnipeg is -16.4.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I have done some more research and found a rather obscure one.

**Pegas Fly** operates a seasonal charter **EO 2479** from [Chita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chita,_Zabaykalsky_Krai#Climate) to [Phuket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phuket_Province#Climate), every two weeks, from January to May.

Full schedule can be found on the [Pegas Touristik website](https://agency.pegast.ru/FlightSearch).

In January, there is a staggering difference of 28.1-(-25.2) = **53.3°C**.

It also appears that Nordwind Airlines, of which Pegas Fly is a subsidiary, operates a seasonal charter N4 2521 from [Yakutsk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yakutsk#Climate) (-38.6°C in January) to [Pattaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattaya#Climate) (26.1°C in January).

At a difference of 64.7°C, we would have had the certain winner here. Unfortunately, according to [FlightMapper](https://info.flightmapper.net/flight/Nord_Wind_N4_2521), that flight stops in Irkutsk for an hour, which is about 20°C warmer than Yakutsk.

Answer (score 58):

[Bangkok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bangkok#Climate) to [Ulaanbaatar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulaanbaatar#Geography_and_climate) in January: 27.0 °C – (–21.6 °C) = **48.6 °C**.

Nonstop flights are operated by MIAT Mongolian Airlines, twice weekly (Wednesday and Saturday) from November to March.  [Timetable](https://www.miat.com/timetableimg.php?s=winter&lang=en).

Comment: Seems like the real gem is in Mongolia!

Comment: Ding ding ding, this is likely the winner: UB is the world's coldest capital city, so this will be tough to beat.

Answer (score 27):

I nominate S7 6330 [Phuket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phuket_Province#Climate)–[Irkutsk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irkutsk#Climate) in January. 28,1 – (–17,8) = **45,9 °C**.

Comment: Russia is always a good place to look! I have found a similar one, Bangkok-Khabarovsk S7 6445 in January, difference 27.0-(-19.8) = 46.8℃

Answer (score 20):

I nominate Harbin-Singapore, operated by Scoot (TR 155). The mean temperature in [Harbin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harbin) is -17.6°C in January, while in Singapore it's 26.5°C, for a total difference of **44.1°C**. The flight time is 7.5 hours. Yakutsk is significantly colder with a daily mean of -38.6° in January, but there aren't direct flights to any warm cities from Yakutsk airport during the winter.

Comment: That's a good one, I wasn't looking in that direction at all!

Answer (score 10):

A comment noted that all answers to date have both cities in the northern hemisphere (winter in January), so here's one with one end in the **southern hemisphere** (winter in July).

[image]
(courtesy [mapsofworld.com](https://www.mapsofworld.com/world-maps/averages-temperature-july-enlaged-map.html))

In general, the southern hemisphere has a lot less land mass than the north, and (AFAIK) not a single major city where daily mean winter temperatures go negative.  The best I could find is **Dubai to Buenos Aires**, with 35.5 - 7.4 in July, for a comparatively puny temperature difference of **28.1°C**.

For other temperature hunters, Riyadh is slightly hotter (36.8) but has less long-distance flights, while Doha and Abu Dhabi are very slightly cooler.  On the cool side, Johannesburg hits 9.6 in June (10.0 in July) while Auckland clocks in at a balmy 10.9.

Comment: The Wikipedia page for DXB shows a flight to Christchurch, NZ (CHC) which would be slightly better (averaging 5.7C in July), but unfortunately that flight isn't nonstop; it stops in Sydney.

Comment: there's really no need to cross the equator, the tropical zone is hot all year round.

Comment: @Jasen The Middle East is much hotter than the tropics during the northern summer.

Answer (score 8):

I will nominate my personal experience although this may count as an outlier case. 
In February / March 2018, there was a storm called [Beast from the East](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_Great_Britain_and_Ireland_cold_wave) that hit quite a few parts of Europe.

I had to fly from Munich to Chennai during the end of Feb, via Frankfurt (LH 758) with a 2 hour halt.

- Temperature in Munich = -18
- Temperature in Frankfurt = -10
- Temperature in Chennai = 34

Difference between Munich (-18) and Chennai (34) = 52 degrees

Difference between Frankfurt (-10) and Chennai (34) = 44 degrees

I was sitting with my multi layered jacket for a really long time after the flight took off from Frankfurt; I felt like I was melting when I landed in Chennai.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a non-stop flight as requested by OP. Else I would nominate my personal experience of flying from Sir Seewoosagur Ramgoolam International Airport, Mauritius back to Riga, Latvia at around January  1st. From +31C to -22C: **53 degree change**. But (a) it was via Frankfurt (or was it Vienna?), and (b) this is not necessarily the mean temperature in Riga. Nevertheless it was memorable, not least for the fact that it didn't feel cold at all in Riga. And incidentally after experiencing this drop, I didn't have a cold for at least 3 winters.